# Conditionally change the year part of a date within a dplyr chain

Tags: r, date, dataframe

```
x <- structure(list(SU_BIRTH_DATE = structure(c(47482, 2884, 11347, 
10449, -1280, 2324), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = "SU_BIRTH_DATE")

 x
  SU_BIRTH_DATE
1    2100-01-01
2    1977-11-24
3    2001-01-25
4    1998-08-11
5    1966-07-01
6    1976-05-13
```

From looking over a dataset it's clear that many people have used a typo for date of birth, where they entered 2100 instead of 2001 for the year part.

I want to replace any 2100 year parts of a date field with 2001.

How can I do that?

```
x <- x %>% 
  mutate(SU_BIRTH_DATE = if_else(year(SU_BIRTH_DATE) == 2100, year(SU_BIRTH_DATE) = 2001,SU_BIRTH_DATE))
```

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   "x <- x %>%
>     mutate(SU_BIRTH_DATE = if_else(year(SU_BIRTH_DATE) == 2100, year(SU_BIRTH_DATE) ="

EDIT
Converting to character and using str_replace and then converting back to date is a solution that has worked meantime, but I'm sure there's a smarter, less code way of doing this?

```
   x <- x %>% mutate(SU_BIRTH_DATE = str_replace_all(as.character(SU_BIRTH_DATE), "2100", "2001"),
              SU_BIRTH_DATE = ymd(SU_BIRTH_DATE))
```

Comment: your problem here is that `if_else` (and `ifelse` for that matter) needs the  `true` (or `yes`) argument to actually be something. `year<-` doesn't return anything, and wrapping it in parentheses can't save you here, since it will just return `2001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `year` function form `lubridate` to check and then assign back year. I have used a custom function to explain replace. This allow not to break `dplyr` chain and no conversion to `character`.

One can avoid use of `custom` function by use of `case_when`.

**Option #1**

```
replace_year <- function(x){
  for(i in seq_along(x))
  if(year(x[i]) == 2100){
    year(x[i]) <- 2001
  }
  x
}


x %>% mutate(SU_BIRTH_DATE = replace_year(SU_BIRTH_DATE))
```

**Option #2**: one can avoid use of custom function with use of `case_when`

```
x %>% mutate(SU_BIRTH_DATE = case_when(
  year(SU_BIRTH_DATE) == 2100 ~ `year<-`(SU_BIRTH_DATE, 2001),
  TRUE ~ SU_BIRTH_DATE
  ))

# SU_BIRTH_DATE
# 1    2001-01-01
# 2    1977-11-24
# 3    2001-01-25
# 4    1998-08-11
# 5    1966-07-01
# 6    1976-05-13
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gsub` to replace `"2100"` with `"2001"`, then cast the result `as.Date`.

```
x %>% mutate(SU_BIRTH_DATE = as.Date(gsub("2100", "2001", SU_BIRTH_DATE)));
#  SU_BIRTH_DATE
#1    2001-01-01
#2    1977-11-24
#3    2001-01-25
#4    1998-08-11
#5    1966-07-01
#6    1976-05-13
```

I admit, this is similar to your `str_replace_all` approach, albeit a bit shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to get out of a dplyr pipe. If you want to use `lubridate::year` to assign a new year (a reasonable desire), it won't operate nicely inside the pipe. Do this instead:

```
with(x, year(SU_BIRTH_DATE[SU_BIRTH_DATE == 2100]) <- 2001)
x
  SU_BIRTH_DATE
1    2001-01-01
2    1977-11-24
3    2001-01-25
4    1998-08-11
5    1966-07-01
6    1976-05-13
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple to read and understand answer, it was difficult to choose which to accept